# user input output multiplication table

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multiplication

I need to make a multiplication table that displays the users input from 1-9, so if they enter 3 it will display the multiplication table for 3 from 1-9. it must do this with each number.

I have a for loop working for only 1 number and I dont know what else to do, I'm still really new to this so I'm not sure how to make it work for me.

```
prompt ("please enter a number");
var a = 1;
var b;

for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    b= a*i
    document.write("" + a + "*" + i + "=", + b +"<br>");
}
```

If I enter any number from 1-9 it must display the multiplication from 1-9 for that one number. Must work for each number entered.

Answer (score 2):

the variable a should have the value received from the prompt and not 1

```js
var a = prompt ("please enter a number");
var b;

for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
    b= a*i
    document.write("" + a + "*" + i + "=", + b +"<br>");
}
```

Comment: if it helped you mark it as correct so it can help others too

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variable for the prompt and add it inside your document.write

```js
var question = prompt("please enter a number");
var a = 1;
var b;

for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  b = a * i
  document.write(question + " " + "* " + i + " " + " = ", + b + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the return of the `prompt` function to your `a` variable.
Also, you have to cast this string value to a number to make sure your calculations are correct.

In the snippet below:

- I wrapped the call to `prompt` with the `Number` function to get a number ([MDN doc about Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)).
- I changed the `var` keywords to `let` and `const` as this is preferred over `var`, which declares global variables.
- I replaced the string concatenation with a template string, which is easier to read when building complex strings ([MDN doc on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).

```js
const a = Number(prompt('please enter a number'));

for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    const b = a * i;
    document.write(`${a} * ${i} = ${b}<br>`);
}
```